# Calling web api in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to call my webapi locally. This is my postman url and it work great. http://localhost:8080/api/V1/Students

When calling from MVC application I get an exception 404 not found.

This is my student controller

```
            var url = "/Students";
            string test = ApiHelper.ApiClient.BaseAddress + url;
            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await ApiHelper.ApiClient.GetAsync(url))
            {
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    listStudent = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<StudentModel>>();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception(response.ReasonPhrase);
                }
            }
```

Notice: test actually return the url "http://localhost:8080/api/V1/Students". Witch his good.

And this is my ApiHelper code.

```
    public class ApiHelper
    {
        public static HttpClient ApiClient { get; set; }

        public static void  InitializeClient()
        {
            string ApiBaseUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApiUrl"];
            ApiClient = new HttpClient();
            ApiClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(ApiBaseUrl);
            ApiClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            ApiClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        }
    }
```

When I debug it I found that on my response the Request URI

```
RequestUri  {http://localhost:8080/Student}
```

This is where my api location is called

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ApiUrl" value="http://localhost:8080/api/V1" />
  </appSettings>
```

What I am doing wrong in trying to call the local api?

Comment: try to call `GetAsync(url)` with `api/V1/Students` instead `/Students`

Comment: This did the work, however why would i put api/v1 in all my web api call this sound overkill.

Comment: i don't know how you defined the route for the API, but i tried to add just `[Route("api/V1/[controller]")]` and i call it by `GetAsync("/Students")`. and it's work fine

Comment: No, What I meant to say is if I do GetASync(api/V1/Students)  it works, but declaring [route(...)] for every controller/method seems tedious to write it on every single method/controller. what if i want to change from v1 to v2, I then need to change all my method from route(api/v1... to route(api/v2...) this is kinda why i created the apihelper so i could have my based element in one central location. Your solution but on each controller. I may have thousand controller in the future. But yes your solution does work.

Comment: In this case, change url by test for GetAsync method. And will work to

Comment: I think i understand what your saying, just unclear on by test, did you mean case by cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

api/v1 is a route prefix. Decorate your BaseAddress controller with this route prefix and tray again. Like so:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/V1")]  
    public class ProductController : Controller  
    {
```